# Erro ao criar relaçoes no MySql usando WampServer

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, wamp, wampserver

Montei todo o banco de dados e agora estou tentando fazer as relaçoes, quando clico na chave primareia(referencial) e clico na chave estrangeira, aparece o seguinte erro: "Erro: As características relacionais estão desactivadas!"
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolvo o problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que tipo de base você criou? MyISM ou InnoDB?

Comment: Não sei te responder, só abri o wamp e criei a base de dados

Comment: Ali nas propriedades da base de dados você tem que analisar isso. Veja onde são exibidas as tabelas também, vai exibir as propriedades dela.

Comment: Postei a imagem ta tela do banco, acho que é MyISAM

Answer (score 4):

As tabelas MyISAM não suporta FOREIGN KEY.

Logo tens que alterar os tipo da base de dados para InnoDB?

Isso você consegue selecionar no momento de criar a base de dados, e antes de criar as tabelas.

Answer (score 1):

No PHPMyAdmin, basta entrar em cada tabela, clicar na aba **Operações** e depois alterar o "Motor de armazenamento" para **InnoDB**, depois EXECUTAR.

Depois disso, tente novamente criar as relações.

[image: painel do PhpMyadmin - Operações]